# #include <deque> on Xcode4

Tags: c++, xcode

I use Xcode 4.0.2 (latest update for Snow Leopard) and want to know how to include this C++ standard library and other like this.

I read some questions and answer by changing .m file to .mm files. But I don't know how to add a .mm file into my project, when I click on add a new file only see class file and other options different to .mm files.

But, It's possible to include the deque file header into a m file and to add it.

Thanks.

Comment: Xcode 4.2.1 is the latest version for Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the .m file, then rename it to .mm